# How to modify a column in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` in R which looks like this:

```
        nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA percent.mt rat_clusters cluster_id group_id
1       11261        2946   4.466744             1          1     med1
1       10791        2689   5.208044             1          1     med1
1       6477         1641   3.597344             0          0     SAR1
1       6073         1558   2.66754              0          0     SAR1
```

for the last column, I want to edit it and remove the number at the end of each item in that column. here is the expected output:

```
        nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA percent.mt rat_clusters cluster_id group_id
1       11261        2946   4.466744             1          1     med
1       10791        2689   5.208044             1          1     med
1       6477         1641   3.597344             0          0     SAR
1       6073         1558   2.66754              0          0     SAR
```

I know maybe `mutate` function helps but do not know how exactly do it. could you help?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be through `gsub`. Here the regular expression captures any number of digits (`\\d+`) that immediately precede the end of the string (`$`), and removes them.

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe <- dataframe |>
  mutate(group_id = gsub('\\d+$', '', group_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

or something like this:

```
people = data.frame(name = c("Andrew", "Mathew", "Dany", "Philip", "John", "Bing", "Monica"),
                    age = c(28, 23, 49, 29, 38, 23, 29),
                     income = c(25.2, 10.5, 11, 21.9, 44, 11.5, 45))



for (i in 1:nrow(people)) {

people$name[i] <- substr(people$name[i], 1, nchar(people$name[i])-1)

}
```